# Domains to ip:port forwarder (2 servers, 15 domains, 1 IP)

Tags: dns, routing, http, xforwarding

I have 1 external IP address, but 2 web-severs (one is IIS and another is Apache) in network that host around 15 domains.

I need a solution that would check all port 80 requests, detect which domain this request came from and redirect/reroute this to appropriate IP.

Therefore, all web requests must be re-routed to appropriate servers.

Is there anything like this available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty convoluted, but perhaps it will work:
- put one server on port 80 and one on port 82
- create virtual sites based on host headers on both servers
- On the port 80 server, create rewrite rules to rewrite the requests for the port 82 server to use port 82

So say www.site1.com is on the port 80 server and www.site2.com is on the port 82 server

When a request for site2.com comes in, the port 80 server would rewrite to www.site2.com:82.

Finally, you would need to set a port forwarder on your router to forward requsts on Port 82 to the internal IP of server 2.

Comment: probably you don't need different ports as your apache and iis are probably on a different machines.